# why does this regex lead to catastrophic backtracking?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to match everything after the first occurrence of a table element and before closing a body tag in an html document.

This is the regex that I tried with:

```
(?:<table>(.|\s)*<\/table>)((.|\s)*)(?:<\/body>)
```

I got no matches for this regex.  I'm using JavaScript.

When I switch to PHP mode on regex101.com, I notice that this regex leads to catastrophic backtracking.  I've isolated the section that breaks it, and apparently it's this:

```
<table>(.|\s)*<\/table>
```

What's wrong with this expression?

Comment: `.` character matches everything

Comment: Since a closing table tag should not appear outside the body anyway, what is the point of worrying about a closing body tag?  By the way, don't use regex to parse HTML.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I don't understand your question.  I'm not interested in what's inside of the first table, that's why it's a non-capturing group.  Everything after that group and before the closing body tag is what I need to match.

Comment: What is wrong with using `<table>.*<\/table>` ?

Comment: NEVER use `(.|\s)*` in the middle of the pattern. `.` can match line breaks in the latest Chrome versions if you use `s` modifier, but a more portable solution is to replace `.` with `[\s\S]` (it will work in any regex) or `[^]` (only works with ECMAScript).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Unfortunately, the highest-voted answer in your dupe recommends that syntax. I know you commented there a while ago, but he didn't fix the answer.

Comment: @Barmar I do not care about high voted answers. There is an answer that provides all necessary details to solve the problem in many languages efficiently.